# Calculate number of states in edge triggered flip flops

Tags: flipflop, state-machines

Consider the sequential circuit shown in the figure, where both flip-flops used are positive edge-triggered D flip-flops.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzc9NH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The number of states in the state transition diagram of this circuit that have a transition back to the same state on some value of “in” is _.

My question is how can we calculate a number of states in above diagram. Is there any formulae for that or any logic to calculate?

Comment: 2 binary registers. How many combinations they can have?

Comment: only 2 according to that. But if there are 4 combinations then the answer is 4 ?

Comment: How is it 2? Not really. Yes, it is 4. 2^2. BTW, if you look closer, you will identify a 2 bit SISO shift register here.

Comment: If you can explain that supporting your answer. It will be really helpful thanks.

Comment: It can be 00, 01, 10, 11, right? Can you think why it can't be any of these? Can you think of anything else?

Comment: I find `some value of “in”` too vague. If both FF start low and `in` goes high for one clock and then low one clock later you get a different number of states then when it stays high for two clocks. A similar argument can be held for both FF starting high and `in` going low.

Comment: Yep. Four states... and two for each FF.

Comment: If clock is high then it will remain high for both registers. In that case one signal is from clock and another one is from input. If I am right ?

Comment: Clock states or clock signal are usually disregarded when speaking of state machines. It is only triggering transitions between states.

Comment: Then how it is defined there are going two states for each Register.

Comment: Because we're talking about binary logic, right? Every signal, including the outputs of FFs can only have two states, by definition.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two FFs can be in a total of 2<sup>2</sup> = 4 states altogether. An appropriate pattern of bits on `Input` can drive the machine to any given state.

However, the actual question is more subtle than that: How many states can make a transition to a particular state?

The serial connection between the FFs implies that there's a limitation — what is it?

Answer (score 0):

The Q output of first FF can be 0/1 and for each, the Q output of second FF can be 0/1. That gives a total of four states - 00,01,11,10.  <s>However, (correct me if I am wrong) both Q will have to be the same since both FF are activated by same edge of clock. In, other words the clock edge that enables first flip flop also enables the second flip flop. So I think we can only achieve the 00 or 11 states.</s>   A correct explanation is in comments.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Unless stated otherwise, the output of a FF doesn't change until after the clock edge, and the input is only sensitive to changes before the clock edge.

Comment: I am sorry. I need a more elaborate explanation. Is there a reference I can get? I know that being edge triggered, the FF samples only at the edge, further changes in D won't be carried to Q for the remaining part of the cycle. So if for the first clock edge, the input was 0, it sets, the first Q to zero. On the next clock edge if input was 1, the first Q is set to 1, but the value available at the D of second FF is still 0 (due to Q first being zero) when clock goes high. Is this how a 10 state can be reached?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.